# How to write a regression formula with dummy variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding

my regression is relatively simple. I have a dependent variable, age (A), and its values for 8 types of employees (T) for 6 years (Y). I run it in R and get some meaningful results, which show how A depends on T, controlling for the year. I can also see some changes over time. My problem is that I do not quite know how to write it down in a proper math format. T and Y are dummy variables, so it's something like:

A(i,j) = a + b x T(i) + c x Y(j) + e(i,j)

Is this a correct way to present it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model can be represented as

$$A_{ij}= a + \sum_{i^\prime=1}^8 b_{i^\prime}T_{i\cdot i^\prime}+\sum_{j^\prime=1}^6 c_{j^\prime} Y_{j\cdot j^\prime} +\varepsilon_{ij},\tag 1$$

where $T_{i\cdot i^\prime}, Y_{j\cdot j^\prime}$ are dummy $(0,1) $ variables with $T_{i\cdot i^\prime} :=\delta_{ii^\prime}, ~Y_{j\cdot j^\prime}:= \delta_{jj^\prime} .$ It is assumed the $(i, j) $ cell contains one observation.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much.

Comment: If you think it answered your query, you might accept that if you want.

Comment: Yes, thank you, and sorry for the delay